# Least number $k$ , such there is no graph with $n$ nodes and $k$ hamilton-cycles

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Let $f(n):=$min{ $ k \in N$: There is no graph with $n$ nodes and $k$ hamilton-cycles} for $n\ge 3$

The values I found out so far :

$$f(3)=2$$
$$f(4)=2$$
$$f(5)=3$$
$$f(6)=9$$
$$f(7)=13$$
$$f(8)=89$$
$$f(9)=485$$

It is clear that $f(n)\le \frac{(n-1)!}{2}+1$ because the $K_n$ has $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ hamilton-cycles and more than that is imposssible for graphs with $n$ nodes.

My questions :

- How can $f(n)$ be calculated efficiently ? Is there an algorithm to decide efficiently if there is a graph with $n$ nodes and $k$ hamilton-cycles for a given pair $(n,k)$ ?
- Is $f(n)$ a strictly motonon increasing function ?

  Especially, I am interested in the value of $f(10)$.

Comment: $\large f(10)$ is greater than $1800$